HCL Domino v.12/14 on Rocky Linux 9: Delay writing to console.log
On a Rocky Linux v.9 server with HCL Domino v.12 (or v.14, it makes no difference) I installed fail2ban to block attempts to access the SMTP port with incorrect username or password by analyzing console.log, and it works correctly.
In the fail2ban filter I put this line:
failregex = .* Authentication failed .* connecting host <HOST>

and the remote IP is blocked by fail2ban when the line in the console.log matches, like this:
SMTP Server: Authentication failed for user info@domain.tld ; connecting host 11.22.33.44

So far so good, but the problem arises from the fact that it takes a loooong time before these lines are written to the log, allowing the remote server to send dozens (if not hundreds) of authentication requests before fail2ban notices and blocks it.
So my question is: is there a flag in Hcl Domino, or a line to put in notes.ini, to decrease the delay time between the attack on the SMTP port and the writing of the line to the log?
And if there is nothing like this, what other way can I use to block these attacks and avoid all this useless traffic?
Thanks in advance to everyone.

Fail2Ban is the right approach to block authentication events. SNMP and Domino event monitoring are more intended for alerting and long term monitory. Fail2ban allows to block attackers on Linux firewall level.
I am not aware of a long delay for IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT/console.log.
What does "loooong time" mean? Can you quantify this in seconds?
When you use my Domino Start Script, there is another file written "notes.log" in the data directory. In contrast to console.log this file is a redirect from the server process stdout and is not rotated.
It is automatically managed by the start script.

It's archived as a compressed tar and named properly
There are retention times you can specify

This log is better suited for Fail2Ban integrations.
The Start Script project also provides a Fail2Ban integration for internet protocols.
And it also provides a script to manage this fail Fail2Ban integration.
Here is the link to the documentation page where you also find the Domino start script Nash!Com Domino Fail2Ban.
If you have questions or feedback, please open issues directly on Github

I think a better fit than scanning the console.log will be leveraging the Event system in events4.nsf, https://help.hcl-software.com/domino/14.0.0/admin/admn_monitoringthedominosystem_c.html
Using event handlers: https://help.hcl-software.com/domino/14.0.0/admin/admn_eventhandlers_t.html
There are lots of possible choices what to do if the event occurs: https://help.hcl-software.com/domino/14.0.0/admin/admn_eventhandlernotificationmethods_r.html
Likely candidates seem logging to the Unix log or running an agent, or possibly sending an SNMP trap.

This seems to be the right way, I'll look into it in detail. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll let you know once it works (and how I did it, if I succeed).
